# Regular expression for atleast one letter

Tags: php, regex

Hi I need to use php's pregmatch to check a string is valid. In order to be valid the string needs to have at least one alphabetic character and allows characters ,numbers and periods.But there should not be two dots adjacent

Comment: what do you mean by `allows characters` ? What did you tried?

Comment: charcters means english letters,,,,i have tried preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/',$username) to  make sure there is atleast one letter,preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/",$username) for avoid unwanted special characters ,but i need the experssion which allows letters and periods,numbers,there should be atleast one letter and dont allow two consecutive periods

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/ get idea of generating regex according to requirement from here

Answer (score 2):

Use lookaheads for satisying the atleast condition.

```
preg_match('~^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*\.\.)[\w.]+$~',$username)
```

`\w` matches letters , numbers, `_` symbol. `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` Atleast one alphabet. `(?!.*\.\.)` - no consecutive dots. `[\w.]+` Matches one or more word character or dot.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aQ7yS5/1)